# Open mapping thm linear spaces Lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, baire-category, open-map

Extract from Lemma 4.21 M.Einsiedler & T.Ward.

$X$ is a normed space, $Y$ is Banach and $T:X \to Y$ is a bounded surjective linear map. The implication of the lemma shows that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta >0$ such that $B_{\delta}^{Y} \subset \overline{TB_\epsilon^X}$.

... // Since $X=\cup_n nB_\epsilon^X$, $B_\epsilon^X=B_\epsilon^X(0)$, and $T$ is onto, we have $Y= \cup_n nTB_\epsilon^X$. By Baire's Theorem it follows that there is $n \geq 1$ such that the set $n\overline{TB_\epsilon^X}$ contains some ball $B_r^{Y}(z)$ in $Y$. Then, ***by linearity***, $\overline{TB_\epsilon^X}$ must contain the ball $B_{r/n}^{Y}(z/n)$ //...

Why is the argument for linearity repeated in the last sentence, once we have obtained $B_r^{Y}(z) \subset n\overline{TB_\epsilon^X}$? Is it not the case that $\frac{1}{n}B_{r}^{Y}(z)=B_{r/n}^{Y}(z/n)$ and $V \subset nU \implies \frac{1}{n}V \subset U$ for sets $U,V$, so that $B_{r/n}^{Y}(z/n)=\frac{1}{n}B_{r}^{Y}(z) \subset \overline{TB_\epsilon^X}$? The purpose of writing $B_{n\epsilon}^{Y}=nB_{\epsilon}^{Y}$ I would have thought was to make the last line obvious from purely set-theoretical notions.

Comment: You are right. Linearity has been used earlier in writing $Y $ as $\cup_n nTB_{\epsilon}^{X}$ and it is not needed again.

Comment: It is possible that the authors are talking about the linear properties of $Y$, which is a linear space.

Comment: I was thinking, but how would you phrase it if you were asked to clarify that sentence? And basic familiarity has been assumed from the start, and even more so at this point. Doesn't seem to fit the context, or be worth pursuing any further if its agreed that this is not related to any properties of $T$.